# How do I let glade define a GtkDialog's transience

Tags: user-interface, dialog, gtk, glade

I'm trying to create dialogs that 'lock' the parent window, but without touching the `gtk_window_set_transient_for` function.

I notice that Glade allows me to set Transient For and Attach To values, but if I connect those with my parent window (defined in the same glade file) and run the program, it is not transient.

[image]

Do I need to do anything else? Does this way even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it does work. I didn't fully realize however that the a locking dialog also needs to be set to be modal.

So to solve my issue I had to also tick the Modal property.

Furthermore, it's also important that both the dialog and the window are loaded from the same builder instance.